# Multiple File uploads with paperclip without using Nested attributes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, activerecord, paperclip

Whenever I have used paperclip to upload multiple images I have created a separate model called images for example and used the accepts_nested_attributes_for in the associated model..

But what if i want to add multiple images without using this. So for example if my model looks like this

```
class Portfolio < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sector

  attr_accessible :overview, :title, :sector_id, :photo
  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :portfolio => "680x680#"}
end
```

And my form looks like this

```
<%= form_for @portfolio do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :title, "Title", :class => 'title_label' %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>

    <%= f.label :sector_id, "Choose Sector", :class => 'title_label' %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select(:sector_id, Sector.all, :id, :name, :prompt => "Please Select a Sector") %><br>

    <%= f.label :overview, "Overview", :class => 'title_label'  %>
    <%= f.text_area :overview %><br>

    <%= f.file_field :photo %><br><br>


    <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'btn' %>

    <% end %>
```

How would i go about uploading multiple images in this scenario.. Normally within nested form for example i would use the link_to_add helper provided.

I don't have this available though with this scenario so what can i do?

is it best practive to always keep the attachments/photos separate and use nested_attributes?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

To add multiple photos you need to mention, :html => { :multipart => true} in form tag as,

```
<%= form_for(@portfolio, :html => { :multipart => true}) do |f| %>
```

and in file_tag as,

```
<%= f.file_field :photo, as: :file, multiple: true, name: 'photo[photo]' %>
```

name **photo[photo]** so that each photo will get same name and can easily accessed in  controller.
Just dtas it..

NOTE: i consider you are using jquery with paperclip to upload photos. If not try out this n let me knw if it works.. ;)

Comment: thanks for the answer, however how do i actually add another image once ive selected one..

Comment: yes jquery is installed, i guess i need to create something like the link_to_add helper but unsure how to go about it

Comment: oh i see, not selecting an image then selecting another separately

Comment: apologies, seems as if no images are being uploaded at all, doesn't matter if i try 1, 2 or 3